# How can I increase the width and spacing of bootstrap cards

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I've made bootstrap cards that appear on two different pages. One on the landing page which I want to increase the [spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Uuq.jpg) and one on the books page which I want to increase the [width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbZbu.jpg) of the cards. Here's the code that I've written and used in both pages. The only thing that I've changed is on the 6th line from '...col-lg-3' to '...col-lg-2'. If anyone can assist me in adding the spacing and increasing the with of the card, help me if you can. d-flex justify-content-evenly doesn't work when i use col-lg-3.

```
 <section id="about" class="ts-block" >
               <div id="cards_landscape_wrap-2">
    <div class="container " style="width:70%">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <a href="{{route("products.show",$product->slug)}}">
                    <div class="card-flyer ">
                        <div class="text-box">
                            <div class="image-box">
                                <img src="{{asset($product->image)}}" alt="{{$product->title}}" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" width="100%"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                        <i class="text-muted"><strike>Ksh.{{$product->old_price}}</strike></i>
                                        <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">Ksh.{{$product->price}}</span><br>
                                        <span class="mybuttonoverlap btn btn-primary">View</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including `d-flex justify-content-around` to a direct parent containing the cards instead of
`<div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">`. And add margin to the card.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-around">
                <a href="{{route("products.show",$product->slug)}}">
                    <div class="card-flyer m-2">
                        <div class="text-box">
                            <div class="image-box">
                                <img src="{{asset($product->image)}}" alt="{{$product->title}}" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" width="100%"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                        <i class="text-muted"><strike>Ksh.{{$product->old_price}}</strike></i>
                                        <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">Ksh.{{$product->price}}</span><br>
                                        <span class="mybuttonoverlap btn btn-primary">View</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div
```

Comment: I just changed the width from 70% to 100 percent